# Is it possible to do reliability analysis using lifeline library python using nevada data?

Tags: distribution, reliability, weibull, lifelines

I have done some practices for reliability analysis using other libraries in python but I have to find the beta and eta values using lifeline library for nevada data

I need to know the format of input and the value of beta and eta